# 'Initialize Agent' step missing in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure DevOps and had some issues with releasing a container to Azure Web Service.

I have 2 projects which during Build produce a docker image which is stored in an Azure Registry. When a new image is pushed the release pipeline is triggered and deploys it to a azure web service. I have this working, but I noticed a difference in release steps between the 2 project. The step was

[image]

The first step is 'Initialize Agent'. It looks like

[image]

So, in one project I have this step, and in the other I see this

[image]

As I said both work fine, but I cannot explain the difference. If someone has an idea what the reason might be I really would like to know

Answer (score 2):

those are internal Azure Devops steps, nothing you should worry about. there probably is some rationale behind this, but you'd need somebody from the product group to explain that.

Comment: with `product group` you mean someone from azure support?

Comment: product group - people working on\creating azure devops. support wont help you here, most likely